# Is my ginger beer safe to drink?

Tags: fermentation, ginger-beer, safety

While fermenting ginger beer I found out after 24 hrs of fermentation there's this white layer on the top of surface has grown.Is it safe to drink?[image: white layer on top of beer while fermenting]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's safe to drink.

It could potentially have some type of wild bacteria (lacto perhaps), although depending on the brew ingredients this could just be some coagulated oils etc. However, it won't hurt you either way, although introduction of wild yeast could create some off-flavors.